# Spring maven , access CSS/JS files

Tags: javascript, css, spring, maven

I have a Spring project:

Resource files are under : `src/main/resources/style/`.........lots of subfolders

servlet.xml:

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

and my jsp:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/style/jquery_ui/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css"/>
```

When I browse to my view, gives this link as location:

```
http://localhost:8080/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/style/jquery_ui/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css
```

How can I get it to show css file correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard Maven layout has web resources located in `src/main/webapp/resources`. The `src/main/resources` is more for library and Java resources.

Referencing them in your JSP is easily done with the [JSTL core](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) [`c:url` tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html). You don't need to worry about context root when using these. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/style/jquery_ui/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" />" />
```

The library will automatically prepend the context root to this URL.